# Загрузка данных до компиляции шаблонов AngularJS. Пагинация angular-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularstrap

Есть `json` с базовыми данными, которые нужны во всех частях приложения, гружу с помощью `$http.get('some.json').success(callbackFunc);`.
Необходимо выводить список с пагинацией, причем отображать номер страницы в адресе `some.com/list?page=5` (чтобы в последствии можно было по этому адресу на соответствующую страницу зайти).

Для пагинации, как вы уже поняли, использую **angular-bootstrap**:

```
   <uib-pagination
        items-per-page="20"
        max-size="10"
        boundary-links="true"
        total-items="listCount"
        ng-model="currentPage"
        ng-change="pageChanged()"
        class="pagination-sm"
        previous-text="&lsaquo;"
        next-text="&rsaquo;"
        first-text="&laquo;"
        last-text="&raquo;"
    ></uib-pagination>
```

а в контроллере

```
$scope.currentPage = $location.search().page
```

но вот в чем загвоздка, когда приложение запускается данных еще нет и `listCount = 0`, п.э. пагинатор сбросит номер страницы на `1` и отработает функция `pageChanged`:

```
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
    $location.search('page', $scope.currentPage);
}
```

Подскажите как мне загрузить данные до компиляции шаблонов?

Хотелось бы без костылей решение найти ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) есть опция `resolve` в которой можно указать функцию которая будет возвращать промис вашего http запроса который подгружает стартовые данные. В этом случае раутер подождет резолва промиса перед инициализацией контроллера.

> resolve - `{Object.<string, function>=}` - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of
>   these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to
>   be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated.

**Update (примерно так):**

```js
app.config(
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'app.tpl.html',
        resolve: AppCtrl.loadMyData
      })

    .state('app.dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.tpl.html',
      controller: 'dashboardController',
      controllerAs: 'dCtrl'
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Использую ui.router. Там тоже имеется, но как мне прописать загрузку при любом url или state?

Comment: Можно задать базовый абстрактный `state` у которого указать `resolve`, а остальные `state` приложения наследовать от него.